# Как пофиксить radio button?

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование

У меня не возвращаются к исходному стилю radio при выборе других, все остаются в стиле как :checked

```css
.slider__buttons input[type="radio"] {
    display: none;
}

.slider__buttons label {
    background-color: #00aeef;
    margin-right: 30px;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: left;
}

.slider__buttons input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #d30054;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider__buttons marginfix">
    <input type="radio" id="radio1" checked>
    <label for="radio1"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio2">
    <label for="radio2"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio3">
    <label for="radio3"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio4">
    <label for="radio4"></label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.slider__buttons input[type="radio"] {
    display: none;
}

.slider__buttons label {
    background-color: #00aeef;
    margin-right: 30px;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: left;
}

.slider__buttons input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #d30054;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider__buttons marginfix">
    <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="rb" checked>
    <label for="radio1"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="rb">
    <label for="radio2"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="rb">
    <label for="radio3"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="radio4" name="rb">
    <label for="radio4"></label>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо) Сам почему-то не заметил.

Comment: @Илья Не за что, впредь будьте внимательнее :)